# Wrong checked on radio button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, components, checked

I have a number of objects that show the component to the user based on the type in those objects, and by clicking on the next stall, both the answer will be sent to the server and the next question will be displayed.

Clicking on the next question changes the index value and displays the component to be viewed:

[image]

But I'm in trouble. When there are multiple choice questions, I use the radio button to select one option.
When he selects option one for the first question and hits the next question, the second question is also checked for one.

I use 4 inputs as follows, only the amount of value is different

```
<input
   type="radio"
   id={`optionOne${number}`}
   name={number}
   value={'1'}
   onChange={e => setOneAnswer(e)}
/>
```

Comment: you need to add required piece of code, where issue is coming

Comment: @ Rahul Kumar My problem is that I do not see any problem, just checked a radio button، for the next component, which is the same. I was very confused

Comment: Try creating a reproducible demo using http://codesandbox.io/